# ISNA + Vlookup function not working but vlookup function works before

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I set different variable and want to run a formula as follows, however I can run it in excel but cannot run it in vba, attached is for reference. Please notice that all variable are set correctly because I can run a vlookup formula before, but I can't run it after I added if isna function.

```
    For iStyleD = lrStyleD To 1 Step -1
            If Range(ColLstatus & iStyleD).Value2 = "" Then
                Range(ColLstatus & iStyleD).Value2 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(" & ColLstatus & iStyleD & ",'C:\Excel\halo\[abc.xlsx]Details'!R6C4:R210C5,1,FALSE)), ""NO"", ""YES"")"
            End If
    Next iStyleD
```

Comment: Change `.Value2` to `.Formula` on the formula line.

Comment: Are you mixing R1C1 and A1 notation? What is `ColLstatus`? You have `R6C4:R210C5` in the vlookup. What should the final formula look like?

Comment: You're creating a circular reference since the cell with the formula is also the cell you're using as the lookup value.

Comment: if I remove range(ColLstatus & iStyleD).value2 = "" , everythings is fine

Comment: 1004 runtime error even i changed it @ScottCraner